# Create custom Audio Effect in Android

Tags: android, uuid, audioeffect

I'm working on Android 11, and trying to create my own AudioEffect. Some audio effects already exist by default, and are derived from AudioEffect.java base class, like BassBoost. Should I derive my effect from AudioEffect base class? And it seems the UUID is needed and to be defined in AudioEffect.java. How to create that UUID for my own audio effect?

Could anyone give me some hints? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: There is an API for creating Audio Effects https://source.android.com/devices/audio/audio-effects

Comment: This info can be helpful https://www.programmersought.com/article/99361763687/

Comment: @Mian did you figure out how to create your own audio effect? Please share your solution as I’m also trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Native example https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/audio-echo but little complicated for the same effect only